# Building a jar without rerunning the compile steps

Tags: gradle

I am trying to set up a build environment whereby I have a job that runs the standard gradle jar task to assemble a release candidate jar. I then want to run some manual tests and if all works well I want to create a new jar with the same artifacts in it. I do not want to recompile anything just generate a new jar with a different name, release candidate jars have a .rcXXX on the end of them.

Making sure that the .class files are correct will be handled outside of Gradle, it is just the gradle config that I am interested in.

I tried setting project.classes { onlyIf { false } } which skips the classes task but for some reason the compileJava tasks still runs if the source changes.

I also tried removing the compileJava dependency on jar (just to test it) and setting outputs.upToDateWhen { false } for compileJava but they seem to be ignored.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve here. Why can't you just copy the existing Jar file?

Comment: The jar file has an embedded pom which has version details within it. I want consistency between the jar name and the pom. I have worked out why the above is not working, it is because it is part of a multi-project build and the other jars are changing. I now have another issue which I shall ask about on another post.

Answer (score 0):

Are You using `clean` option? When specified all the data prepared in previous build will be removed and everything will be rebuilt from scratch.

Don't know all classes are compiled once again, shouldn't be. Any minimal working example?

Also You may build both jar files at once and, then do tests and if everything is correct just release the second jar with different name.